# How to replace one element with multiple elements in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, nested-lists, replaceall

I have a nested list as follows:

```
bpas = {{1, 1/19, 3}, {2, 3/19, 3}, {3, 7/19, 1}}
```

I want to replace the element whose first part equals to `2` with more than one element.
In this case it would be `{2, 3/19, 3}`, replaced by `{2, 6/19, 3}, {1, 1/19, 6}`.

Say, I want to get the following form:

```
bpas = {{1, 1/19, 3}, {2, 6/19, 3}, {1, 1/19, 6}, {3, 7, 7/19, 1}}
```

I used the syntax `bpas /. {x_ /; x == 2, y_, z_} -> {{2, 2 y, z}, {1, y/3, 2 z}}`, but only getting:

```
{{1, 1/19, 3}, {{2, 6/19, 3}, {1, 1/19, 6}}, {3, 7/19, 1}}
```

So, how can I get the proper output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bpas /. {x_ /; x == 2, y_, z_} -> Sequence[{2, 2 y, z}, {1, y/3, 2 z}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bpas = {{1,1/19,3},{2,6/19,3},{1,1/19,6},{3,7,7/19,1}};
bpas/.{head__,{2,y_,z_},tail__}->{head,{2,2y,z},{1,y/3,2z},tail}
```

which returns

```
{{1,1/19,3},{2,12/19,3},{1,2/19,6},{1,1/19,6},{3,7,7/19,1}}
```

BUT that is assuming the triple you want to match does not appear at the beginning or the end of your original `bpas` list. Notice there are 2 `_` following both `head` and `tail`. If the pattern you want to match might appear at the beginning or the end then you should use 3 `_` instead of 2 `_` following `head` and `tail`. You can look up `__` and `___` in the help system to try to understand why this is working.

Test all this VERY carefully before you depend on it.

Comment: Yeah I see, that also works efficiently. Thank you Bill!